# What is the best method to change Year from YYYY to FYYY format in SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, date, to-date

I have year in YYYY format and I want to convert it to FYYY format. So, for instance, 2014 will be FY14, 2009 will be FY09, so on and so forth. I'm creating a View that contains a SUM aggregate function on an amount field. So, the query also contains a Group By clause, just so you are aware.

Comment: Is the fiscal year aligned with the calendar year (running from 1st January to 31st December)?  Or is it misaligned, such as running from July 1st YYYY to June 30th YYYZ, or some other faintly similar period?

Comment: It is aligned with the calendar year.

Comment: That makes life nice and easy and the accepted answer entirely appropriate.

Comment: Aye. Thanks, Jonathan.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A Possible workaround could be

```
'FY'||to_char(to_date(your_year, 'YYYY'), 'YY')
```

`OR` as @Wernfied says like,

```
to_char(to_date(your_year, 'YYYY'), '"FY"YY')
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/35983)

Comment: Works beautifully. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it also without concatenation:

```
to_char(to_date(your_year, 'YYYY'), '"FY"YY')
```